# The remote Oracle WebLogic server is affected by a remote code execution vulnerability

Tags: linux, weblogic

In one of my servers i am getting the above exception. can anyone suggest how to resolve this.

> in the WLS9-async component due to unsafe deserialization of XML
> encoded Java objects. An unauthenticated, remote attacker can exploit
> this, via a  crafted Java object, to execute arbitrary Java code in
> the contex

How to apply the patch on this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known security issue relative to java deserialization mecanism.
You can read details about in this [article](https://www.oracle.com/security-alerts/alert-cve-2019-2725.html) from Oracle. The best thing to do is to apply the latest PSU and CPU published by Oracle.
You can also rename the bea_wls9_async_response.war application from your WebLogic Server installation to prevent the issue.